# c# copy directory during publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish

I want to copy a folder that's contained in another project into the publish directory during website publish, is this possible?

The reason for this is that I have a project with the SQL schema files for creating the database structure, ASP.NET membership schema, alongside some code to run the files against the database. I don't really like having these SQL files in my web project, that just seemed dirty. So I figured I'd store them somewhere else in the solution. But when I deploy I do need them in the publish directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not place these scripts in `App_data`?  It will be deployed along with the rest of the website, and cannot be accessed via client web browsers.  That's what it is there for, to store data associated with your website that you don't want to have in the root for security purposes.

Comment: Sure, but how do I copy them during a publish? I don't want them there (App_Data or not) because it doesn't seem like they belong with the web application to me

Comment: You know, I love running over chavs with cars.  Unfortunately, the way things are, means I cannot do this without being arrested.  So I simply don't do it.  I understand that, to you, they do not seem to "belong", but many orphans have had to fight their way through this preconceived notion.  Do the right thing, Nico!

Answer (score 2):

You can include an extra folder for deployment with all its contents editing the publish profile: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files